# Convertir cada dataframe de un diccionario en un array numpy con un bucle (Python)

Tags: python, array, numpy

Tengo numerosos archivos .csv que he introducido en python creando un diccionario (dos columnas correspondientes a dos csv por cada key) para clasificarlos con más facilidad.

Mi intención ahora es crear un bucle para generar un array por cada key, es decir, una matriz de dos columnas por cada dataframe del diccionario. Aquí es donde tengo mi duda, ya que son demasiados dataframes como para meterlos a mano, y tengo muchos datos (filas) para operar, de ahí que quiera trabajarlos en numpy.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Cual es la duda más precisamente? Edita tu pregunta para agregar el código que tienes, una muestra de los datos de entrada y otra de la salida que esperas obtener. Ahi podremos empezar a trabajar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.